# Continued my work by/with/on analysing

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is correct in the following sentence?

> The first paper of my thesis indicated issues in these patients' ongoing care. Therefore, I continued my work by/with/on analysing these patients' rehabilitation.

Comment: It depends on the context, and there are other prepositions that might be appropriate, again depending on context. You need to give us, as a minimum, the rest of the sentence and possibly some of the rest of the paragraph.

Comment: Thanks! Did so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I continued my work on X* implies that X was already the theme and you carried on with it.

Your paragraph suggests that initial research prompted you to study a new aspect of the topic, so I think *by* would be the best option.